# Unable to load dynamic library php_pdo_oci.dll%1 is not a valid win32 application - phpstorm

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to load the phppdo_oci.dll lib to interact with my oracle database on my website, but I can't load it because of this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Core Warning

Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\ext\php_pdo_oci.dll' - %1 n�est pas une application Win32 valide.

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:
```

I'm using phpstorm and php 5.6.22

Comment: Quite possible that it cannot find some another library that actually used to access Oracle DB (`php_pdo_oci.dll` is just a PHP interface to actual Oracle library).

Comment: In fact I just found it, I had oracle xe 64 bits but it needed 32 bits